# Can I set a default AnnotationBeanNameGenerator in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I'm using `@ComponentScan` multiple places in the test suite for my application. I want to replace the default bean name generation in Spring, so I have made my own generator like this:

```
public class FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {
    protected String buildDefaultBeanName(BeanDefinition definition) {
        return definition.getBeanClassName();
    }
}
```

To use the generator, I'm doing this:

```
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class)
```

The problem is, for every `@ComponentScan` in my test configuration classes (classes annotated with `@Configuration`), I have to repeat `nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class`.

Is it possible for me to tell Spring to always use the `FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator` as a nameGenerator? I want it to be the default one.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39822735/5751473

Answer (score 2):

Just create you own Annotation like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ComponentScan(nameGenerator = FullyQualifiedAnnotationBeanNameGenerator.class)
public @interface MyComponentScan{

}
```

Comment: I did this. I get warning from IntelliJ on the line:
```
@MyComponentScan("my.package")
public class Whatever { ... }
```
Cannot find method "value".

Which makes sense, as the MyComponentScan annotation doesn't have the field "value". I tried to add that, which removes the error, but I have to somehow pass that value to @ComponentScans's value in the MyComponentScan code/annotation. If not, the actual component scanning in Spring won't work.