# How do I prefix each bean id in a package (inc. sub-packages) with a constant string in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

Is there a way to prefix each bean annotated with `@Component` in a certain package and subpackages with a given string?

Say, we have this bean, for example:

```
package com.example.foo;

@Component
class MyBean {}
```

I want all beans in `foo` to be prefixed with `foo`, so that the automatically (by component scan) generated bean id is either `fooMyBean` (preferred, with capital 'M') or `foo-myBean` (instead of the default `myBean`). (The prefix being a String defined somewhere, not being automatically derived from the package name.)

Alternatively, can I achieve this by using custom annotations, like `@FooComponent`, say? (How? ;-) )

Comment: @Component("fooMyBean") http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html

Comment: Well, I was hoping for a slightly more automated/centralised approach... ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring uses a [BeanNameGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanNameGenerator.html) strategy to generate bean names. In particular, the [AnnotationBeanNameGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/AnnotationBeanNameGenerator.html) is the one which generates names for `@Component` classes with the *first-letter-lower-cased* strategy.

You could implement your own `BeanNameGenerator` and apply a custom strategy by inspecting the passed `BeanDefinition`.

If you're using Spring Boot, this can be done right in the [SpringApplicationBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/builder/SpringApplicationBuilder.html).

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static class CustomGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {

        @Override
        public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
            /**
              * access bean annotations or package ...
              */
            return super.generateBeanName(definition, registry);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(DemoApplication.class)
                .beanNameGenerator(new CustomGenerator())
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, how would I a) register my new BeanNameGenerator using plain Spring (not SpringBoot) and b) only call it for beans annotated with a custom annotation, `@MyComponent`, say? (I don't want my naming strategy to affect beans in libraries I imported, because they might reference their beans by id...)

Comment: I have set up my annotation `@Target(ElementType.TYPE) @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Documented @Component public @interface MyC { String value() default ""; }` and my xml config: `<context:component-scan base-package="com.ex.foo"><context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="com.ex.config.MyC"/></context:component-scan><context:component-scan base-package="com.ex.foo" use-default-filters="false" name-generator="com.ex.config.MyAnnotBnNmGen"><context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="com.ex.config.MyC"/>` and now I get 2 beans for every class annoteted with `@MyC` :'(

Comment: Removing the `@Component` annotation from `@MyC` fixed the issue of double-instantiation, but now I can no longer pass an explicit value "foo" in: `@MyC("foo")` - beanName is now `null` in  `AnnotationBeanNameGenerator` :/