# Defining custom bean name generator based on package which the class belong to

Tags: spring-boot, spring-bean

We are planning to create some java libraries and use these common jars in spring boot application by adding them as maven dependencies.

These jars are expected to make use of spring features like creating beans instead of plain java library.

However, it is possible that the client applications already contains beans with the same name as the ones defined in the jar. So to avoid this conflict, I thought of prefixing all the jar beans with some unique name.

So I was hoping I could do the above, specific to beans in a particular package and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39822735/8283737):

```
public static class CustomGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {

    @Override
    public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        /**
         * access bean annotations or package ...
         */
        return "PREFIX-" + super.generateBeanName(definition, registry);
    }
}
```

Not sure if package information is available here.
Also, I am currently testing this out in a spring boot project(2.3.1). But how can I do this in a spring library?

Comment: The `BeanDefinition` class contains a `getBeanClassName()` method. Wouldn't that help you?

Comment: @g00glen00b is correct. `getBeanClassName()` does provide fully qualified name of the bean which contains package name.

Comment: @g00glen00b. yes getBeanClassName() would work, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

The `BeanDefinition` class contains a [`getBeanClassName()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanDefinition.html#getBeanClassName()) method which contains the fully qualified name of the class. This is the classname including the package name.

So you can use that to generate a name. For example:

```java
public static class CustomGenerator extends AnnotationBeanNameGenerator {

    @Override
    public String generateBeanName(BeanDefinition definition, BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) {
        String beanClassName = definition.getBeanClassName();
        if (beanClassName.startsWith("com.xyz.mypkg.lib1")) {
            return "PREFIX-" + super.generateBeanName(definition, registry);
        } else {
            return super.generateBeanName(definition, registry);
        }
    }
}
```